# Google Sheet: How to replace Cell-A with number in Cell-B if the number input is lower than original Cell-B?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, formulas

I am trying to find the lowest value of cell B1 that is constantly being updated.
If B1 is lower than A1, then A1 will be replaced with a new B1 value. 
And if B1 is higher than A1, then A1 retain its previous updated number. 
I am not sure if this can be done with function, script, or if it's even possible to do.

I have this in Cell A1
`"=if(A1<B1,B1,A1)"`

It's giving me error and I am guessing it's because the "value_if_false" is pointing to the cell I put the IF statement in, thus creating an infinite loop.

Comment: can be done with a script. `range.offset` `onEdit()`

Answer (score 1):

Please try in A1:

```
=if(A1>B1,B1,A1)
```

and turn on iterative calculation (which I would not normally recommend). Max. of 1 should be adequate.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have turned on iterative calculation Max of 1, Threshold 0.05. However, it doesn't work for replacing the lower value in B1. It works for replacing higher value. '=if(A1>B1,A1,B1)' and '=if(A1>B1,B1,A1)'  gives the same result, but by changing the greater sign to lesser sign '=if(A1<B1, A1,B1)' the cell returns '0', and changes the value when B1 is negative number.